# How can I set a query for having two Join Relations in one table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a query that merge the results of two queries that work.

I have two tables:

- tblPart[ partnr, manufacturer, supplier]

data ex:

```
 A123 , MAN1 , SUP1
 A125 , MAN1 , SUP2
```

- tblAddress [shortname, longname]

data ex:

```
   MAN1, "Siemens s.p.a."
   SUP1, "Sotre 1"
   SUP2, "Store 2"
```

In the columns of tblPart I have the shortname value for both the fields (manufacturer, supplier) and in the tblAddress I have the longname.
In this moment I have two query:

```
 SELECT tblPart.partnr,tblPart.manufacturer, tblAddress.longname, tblPart.supplier
        FROM tblAddress RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
        tblPart ON tblAddress.shortname = tblPart.manufacturer
```

and the second one:

```
 SELECT  tblPart.partnr,tblPart.manufacturer,  tblPart.supplier, tblAddress.longname
         FROM tblAddress RIGHT OUTER JOIN
         tblPart ON tblAddress.shortname = tblPart.supplier
```

With the UNION operator I have double values. Where I'm in wrong?It's possible to have only one table with : partnr, manufacturer, longname(manufacturer),supplier, longname(supplier)

data ex:

```
 A123 , MAN1 ,"Siemens s.p.a.",  SUP1, "Sotre 1"
 A125 , MAN1 ,"Siemens s.p.a.",  SUP2, "Sotre 2"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *suspect* what you need to do if `JOIN` twice to your table `tblAddress`. To do this you'll need to reverse the joins.

```sql
SELECT P.partnr,
       P.manufacturer,
       M.longname AS ManufacturerLongname
       P.supplier,
       S.longname AS SupplierLongname
FROM dbo.tblPart P
     LEFT JOIN dbo.tblAddress M ON P.manufacturer = M.shortname
     LEFT JOIN dbo.tblAddress S ON P.supplier = M.shortname;
```

Comment: You showed me a new way of referring to tables .... TOP